# Swift: Type cast results in 'Symbol not found'

Tags: swift, linker

In a Swift test bundle, I use the following line to get a class object of a class, which is defined in a dynamically loaded bundle (`MyPlugin`). The bundle contains Swift and Objective-C code and is loaded successfully *before* the following command is executed:

```
let aClass = NSClassFromString("MyPlugin.BackendAPIManager") as! BackendAPIManager.Type
```

When the test tries to execute the line, I get the following runtime error:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __TMaC16MyPlugin17BackendAPIManager
```

When changing the line to

```
let aClass = NSClassFromString("MyPlugin.BackendAPIManager") as! NSObject.Type
```

I can use

```
let apiURL = aClass.perform(#selector(BackendAPIManager.apiUrl(path:)), with: "/something")
```

which means that the class is correctly loaded through the bundle, but somehow I cannot access the class through its name. The corresponding symbol is not found and I have no clue what could cause this. Any ideas?